# How to reshape this database in Excel or R

Tags: excel, transformation

How to transform database organized like A into B-type?

[image]

| fruits | marker | conf_1 | conf_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | C | 123 | 456 |
| Orange | B | 123 | 456 |
| Orange | A | 123 | 456 |
| Apple | C | 987 | 654 |
| Apple | B | 987 | 654 |
| Apple | A | 987 | 654 |
| Plum | C | 321 | 654 |
| Plum | B | 321 | 654 |
| Plum | A | 321 | 654 |
| Pear | C | 765 | 890 |
| Pear | B | 765 | 890 |
| Pear | A | 765 | 890 |
| Grape | C | 235 | 652 |
| Peach | A | 876 | 325 |
| Peach | C | 876 | 325 |

I have this data set in Excel, but also work in R. So I can perform this operation in Excel or in R. But how?

Comment: Can you just set up a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

This PowerQuery would do it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"fruits", type text}, {"marker", type text}, {"conf_1", Int64.Type}, {"conf_2", Int64.Type}}),
    RemoveDuplicate = Table.Distinct(ChangeType, {"fruits", "conf_1", "conf_2"}),

    PivotColumn = Table.Pivot(ChangeType, List.Distinct(ChangeType[marker]), "marker", "fruits", List.Count),
    MergeData = Table.NestedJoin(PivotColumn, {"conf_1", "conf_2"}, RemoveDuplicate, {"conf_1", "conf_2"}, "Fruits", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeData, "Fruits", {"fruits"}, {"fruits"}),
    ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(ExpandData,{"fruits", "A", "B", "C", "conf_1", "conf_2"})
in
    ReorderColumns
```

[image]

Or as @Zack suggested you could use a pivot table.
Pivot tables definitely aren't my strong point, so is probably a better way.

- Add *fruits*, *conf_1* and *conf_2* to the *Rows*.
- Add *marker* to the *Columns* and *Values*.
- Right-click the pivot table and select *PivotTable Options*
  Remove the tick from *grand totals for rows* and *grand total for columns* under the *Totals & Filters* tab.
- In the *Design* tab for the pivot table select *Show in Tabular Form* from the *Report Layout* drop-down.
- Select each of the Totals and right-click and select *Field Settings*.
  Select *None* for the subtotals.

[image]